# Invalid Date in an XML Schema

Tags: xml

My Google Webmaster Tools reported that I have an invalid date format in my .xml file and I don't know why.

The error: 'An invalid date was found. Please fix the date or formatting before resubmitting' occured for this value:

```
2015-05-15T3:43:00-04:00
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please paste the portion of your XML file which is causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one number in the hour. The format should be as follows:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD
```

Change it to:

```
2015-05-15T03:43:00-04:00
```